# Visual Studio error with Entity Framework Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I add Entity Framework Designer, I'm getting an error message

> Error Message An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by
>   an extension.
>
> You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\The
>   Gatwayinfoteh\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

When I look at the log file, I find

> System.ApplicationException: Unable to remove the collapsed region from outlining manager, which means there is an internal consistency issue. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Outlining.OutliningManager.ExpandInternal(ICollapsed collapsed) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Outlining.OutliningManager.UpdateAfterChange(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection changedSpans) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Outlining.OutliningManager.SourceTextChanged(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)

Can anyone see how to interpret this so that I can figure out the error?

Answer (score 0):

You better run the visual studio as administrator.

Check the answers from:

[Error Starting Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738417/error-starting-visual-studio-2012)