# How can I determine which extension is problematic, and how to resolve the exception?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages, activitylog

On opening my ASP.NET Web Pages solution (which I started in WebMatrix) in VS 2013, I am now getting this err msg:

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
>       You can get more information by examing the file '...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'

I searched it for the word "exception" and found this:

```
<description>
System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single 
composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more 
detailed information.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
&#x000A;&#x0009;ContractName&#x0009;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Extensibility.IJavaScriptServicesProvider&#x000
A;&#x0009;RequiredTypeIdentity&#x0009;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Extensibility.IJavaScriptServicesProvider&#x000D;
&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;Resulting in: Cannot set import 
&apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.CommandFilter._javaScriptServicesProvider 
(ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Extensibility.IJavaScriptServicesProvider&quot;)&apos; on part 
&apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.CommandFilter&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Eleme
nt: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.CommandFilter._javaScriptServicesProvider 
(ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Extensibility.IJavaScriptServicesProvider&quot;) --&gt;  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.CommandFilter&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition 
atomicComposition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart 
part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart 
part)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.SatisfyImportsOnce
(ICompositionService compositionService, Object attributedPart)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.CommandFilter..ctor(ITextView 
textView)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.WpfTextViewConnectionListener.HookupCommandFilter
(IWpfTextView textView, IVsTextView textViewAdapter)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Commands.WpfTextViewConnectionListener.SubjectBuffersConnecte
d(IWpfTextView textView, ConnectionReason reason, Collection`1 subjectBuffers)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.ConnectionManager.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__1
()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object 
errorSource, Action call)
</description>
```

...but it still doesn't tell me much, AFAICT. What extension is causing problems, and what can I do about it?

I then searched for "extension" and found these entries:

```
  <entry>
    <record>954</record>
    <time>2015/03/26 15:39:58.007</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MadsKristensen.Image_Optimizer_Extension.Image_Optimizer_ExtensionPackage, 
Image Optimizer Extension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16b83d3f826a86c5]</description>
    <guid>{BF95754F-93D3-42FF-BFE3-E05D23188B08}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>955</record>
    <time>2015/03/26 15:39:58.491</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MadsKristensen.Image_Optimizer_Extension.Image_Optimizer_ExtensionPackage, 
Image Optimizer Extension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16b83d3f826a86c5]</description>
    <guid>{BF95754F-93D3-42FF-BFE3-E05D23188B08}</guid>
  </entry>
```

...and:

```
  <entry>
    <record>963</record>
    <time>2015/03/26 15:40:13.623</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]</description>
    <guid>{30DB8F9B-EC9F-44D6-B377-83C7C27A1A8B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>964</record>
    <time>2015/03/26 15:40:13.717</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]</description>
    <guid>{30DB8F9B-EC9F-44D6-B377-83C7C27A1A8B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
```

...but it seems the "exception" entry is the key one.

My guess is that the JavaScript extension is what is hosed up, as the JavaScript is no longer colorized - it's just white on black:

[image]

Still, I don't know what to do about it.

**Note:** This project did open the first couple of times with no exception. It just decided it didn't like some extension last night. What changed?

Anyway, the entire ActivityLog.xml can be accessed from [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C150662F95F0ACCE!21346&authkey=!AEPolu7DTFFm1o0&ithint=file%2Ctxt)

### UPDATE

My jQuery has got its color back; perhaps it had to do with updating several packages that the flag next to "Quick Launch" in the NE corner was trying to draw my attention to. These were:

1. Developer Assistant
2. Image Optimizer
3. Open from Azure Websites
4. Release Management tools for VS (it failed the first time I tried to install it, and had to run VS as administrator for it to *take*)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738417/error-starting-visual-studio-2012) it might be of some help to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, check the "race car flag" in the NE corner of VS to see if it's apprising you of any updates; if so, apply these updates. This worked in my case. Specifically, I updated:

1. Developer Assistant
2. Image Optimizer
3. Open from Azure Websites
4. Release Management tools for VS

...and the problem went away.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I had to updated `Microsoft Azure` and it seemed to work. However, after restarting Visual Studio 2015, I was met with the same error when trying to add an ADO.NET entity data model. The answer posted here helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31899210/1244630