# Error in Visual Studio 2015 When Add New WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

**When I add new WebForm to my project, I get the following error:**

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS,Version=14.0.0.0 , Culture=neutral ,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.the system
>   can not find the file specified.

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Error]

I tried to create new website project and I tried to reinstall VS 2015 but this did not help.

Comment: Please do not follow the selected answer to this question, it is incorrect. It will fix the problem but only temporarily. As soon as you do any other setup action, such as installing another TypeScript update, it will uninstall the JavaScript Language Service again and you will be back in a broken state. The second answer will fix the problem permanently. Disclosure: I work for Microsoft, and my team wrote the workaround steps cited here: http://min.qa/k1KrJesT

Comment: If the newer Microsoft-endorsed answer below works for you, please consider accepted it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A **temporary** solution:

Shut down Visual Studio and reinstall the following package from the DVD or ISO:

```
x:\packages\JavaScript_LanguageService\JavaScript_LanguageService.msi
```

[A better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32192398), endorsed by Microsoft, has been posted.

Comment: -1 because the right answer should be to update your extensions - there's a v1.1 update to the Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development which fixes this bug.  Just do that and all is good.

Comment: Please everybody, do not follow these steps. They will fix the problem, but the next time you run any setup action it will revert the fix. The steps I outlined below will work. Disclosure: I work for Microsoft.

Answer (score 23):

This is a known bug with Visual Studio 2015. The [officially-endorsed solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/147cd1a2-1f1a-4847-a256-0613cfea732d/rtm-known-issue-visual-studio-hangs-when-creating-a-new-cordova-project-or-intellisense-doesnt?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues) from Microsoft has been posted on MSDN:

> **If the “Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development” are still installed:**
>
> 1. Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2105, click Change.
> 2. In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
> 3. Deselect the feature “Tools for Universal Windows App Development”
> 4. Select “Tools for Universal Windows App Development” again, and click Update.
>
> **If you have already uninstalled the “Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development”:**
>
> 1. Reinstall “Tools for Universal Windows App Development”
> 2. Or take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript project system and language service:
>
>    a. Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, e.g.,
>      vs_community.exe.
>
>    b. Open a CMD window, and run the following command: 
>      vs_community.exe /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden
>      /passive

Comment: Just do a VS Extensions update and you will see a pending v1.1 update for the "Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development" extension. That should fix the bug and you won't have to mess with any of the VS setup yourself.

Comment: Strangely enough that does not always seems to fix it! Sometimes it does though.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answer will work, but only temporarily. As soon as you do any other setup action, such as installing another TypeScript update, it will revert the fix and you will be back in a broken state. Please follow the steps in this answer. Disclosure: I work for Microsoft.

Comment: Hey, that link is broken (my work proxy actually flags it as unsafe!) and there's a typo in the answer ("2105").

Comment: I fixed the link for you.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the update received for visual studio TypeScript on 11/08/2015. it seems to be buggy. After removing TypeScript update, my VS is working fine ;-)

and if you try to reinstall x:\packages\JavaScript_LanguageService\JavaScript_LanguageService.msi from the installation package, soon or later you will face one more problem that "Something went wrong.. may be because of a extension.."
Easiest way is to remove TypeScript update for now. TypeScript future update may fix the problem.

OR

1. Run command prompt as administrator.
2. CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
3. devenv /updateconfiguration
4. devenv /clearcache

Comment: I didn't have an ISO available since I use Community edition and the web installer, but I was able to find TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 1.5.4.0 in Add or Remove Programs and uninstall from there. However, this did not resolve my issue. My symptom was that I could not add a custom toolbox control to a Visual Studio extensibility project and would receive an identical error to the one mentioned here.

Comment: JavaScript_LanguageService.msi(you can try re-install) should be exist and  update for typescript should be removed. and restart VS.