# Visual Studio Major Issues

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

A few days ago now I tried to install the C++ packages for my VS2015 installation, but it wouldn't install them so I uninstalled the entirety of VS2015 and then reinstalled, but since then I've been getting tons of errors when I start the software, they are like this:

> The 'Visual Studio Component Enumerator Package' package did not load correctly. The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file: 'C:Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

I've attached this log at the bottom of this post.

I get around 10 of these Package errors before I can finally load into the software, but then when I try to either open an existing C# project it says "Unavailable" or if I try to start a new C++ project it says

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCWizards\default.vcxproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.vcxproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that support this type

I have tried the following to fix these issues, and every possible combination of these:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling
- Deleting my %appdata% in both Local and Roaming for VS 14.0
- Deleting Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0
- Repairing the installation
- Uninstalling, cleaning registry, deleting everything I can find RE: Visual Studio and then reinstalling
- devenv /setup, devenv /clearcache, devenv /uninstall /force and then reinstalling, every command line I've found anywhere.

I've been dealing with this issue for a few days and it has completely halted my development process and I'm unable to do anything with VS and it's gotten to the point where I'm extremely frustrated and not sure what to do next.

As far as I can tell there are a lot of packages missing from my installation, but Repairing my installation does not fix this. Is there a way to restore the packages?

Any assistance would be much appreciated, or is there a better forum to post this under?

Activity Log:
http://pastebin.com/pwTJQc4B

Comment: *I've attached this log at the bottom of this post* ... um... I can't see any. Plus, Stack Overflow is **not** a forum.

Comment: Just added the log @Raptor

Comment: I've seen quite a few VS2015 problem questions. Are you guys in uni or something?

Comment: According to the last line of log, you should follow the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874643/error-in-visual-studio-2015-when-add-new-webform) to re-install a specific package (instead of whole VS)