# How to fix error check spelling when open page.aspx, control.ascx Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, spell-checking

When i open file .axp or .ascx, everything text in file not check spelling or syntax, i've updated extension but has yet to fix the problem, Hope everybody help, thanks all!

Image: [error check spelling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei36R.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738417/error-starting-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Thank Ahror Kayumov,
I think that was a very good knowledge to learn. In day depressed and I didn't do anything, the error has been remedied:)))